# FB Comments not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

```
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : '307264182690190', // App ID
                  channelUrl : '//www.gig-links.com/channel.html', // Channel File
                  status     : true, // check login status
                  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });

                // Additional initialization code here
              };

              // Load the SDK Asynchronously
              (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
               }(document));
            </script>


            <div id="bottom" style="float: left; border: 2px solid black; width: 100%;">
                <center>
                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.gig-links.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
```

FB comments don't appear at all. Channel.html exists and I have Facebook connect login working via PHP.
Do I need to require a PHP function of some sort?

Comment: I have no idea? How I do check if it's ran.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `xfbml=1` hash option to the asynchronous script loading:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Comment: Still nothing appears. This is a registered Facebook App. PHP Facebook connect work.